# How do I join 2 tables in SQL with missing data in both tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: A and B.

Table A has the following set-up:

```
| ID | date       | location | sales   |
|----|------------|----------|---------|
| 1  | 2022-01-01 | 1        | 10000   |
| 2  | 2022-01-02 | 1        | 10000   |
| 3  | 2022-01-04 | 1        | 10000   |
|... | ....       | 2        | ....    |
```

So 2022-01-03 has no matching row.

And table B has the following set-up:

```
| ID | date       | location | budget     |
|----|------------|----------|------------|
| 1  | 2022-01-01 | 1        | 10000      |
| 2  | 2022-01-03 | 1        | 10000      |
| 3  | 2022-01-04 | 1        | 10000      |
|... | ....       | 2        | ....       |
```

So 2022-01-02 has no matching row.

I am trying to join the tables together to get the following output

```
|location |  sales   | budget  |
|---------|----------|---------|
|1        |  30000   | 30000   |
|2        |  ...     | ...     |
```

So I can group it on location and get | location ABC | sales 123 | budget 123 |, which is a sum of all the dates grouped but also joined the 2 tables together on date and location.

The query I have now:

```
SELECT SUM(A.sales) AS sales, A.restaurant
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.location= B.location
WHERE A.date between ? AND ? 
GROUP BY A.location
UNION
SELECT SUM(B.budget) AS budget, B.restaurant
FROM A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.restaurant = B.restaurant
WHERE B.date between ? AND ?  
GROUP BY B.restaurant
```

I've tried different types of joins and unions and ended with a query as suggested in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql) to mimic a full outer join. However, with this query I get the following output:

```
| location | column  |
|----------|---------|
| 1        | 30000   |
| 2        | ...     |
| 3        | ...     |
| 1        | 30000   |
| 2        | ...     |
| 3        | ...     |
...
```

These sums are correct but not in 2 separate columns 'sales' and 'budget'.

Is there a way can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to *outer* join

Comment: In the absence of full outer join in mysq, I would also union the two tables and then group by on date and sum the two columns